# Find eigenvalue of $B= I + A^{-1}+A^{-2}+A^{-3}+...$

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

> Given $$A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 \\-1 & 4\end{bmatrix}$$ calculate the eigenvalues of $$B = I + A^{-1} + A^{-2} + A^{-3} + \cdots$$

---

I don't understand which properties to use in order to calculate this. I believe we are going to use the eigenvalues of $A$ in some manner, but I can't understand how. I found the eigenvalues of $A$ to be $2$ and $3$.

Comment: You need a generalization of the following result: If $Av=\lambda v$, and $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(A)v=p(\lambda)v$

Comment: **Hint:** What are the eigenvalues of $A^{-k}$, in terms of the eigenvalues of $A$? And second **hint**: geometric series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with corresponding eigenvector $v \neq 0$, so that $A v = \lambda v$, then
$$ A^k v = \lambda^k v$$
for $k \in \mathbb Z$ (including negative $k$, in the event that $A$ is invertible).
Now hit $B$ with the same vector $v$, so that
$$ \begin{align*} B v &= (I + A^{-1} + A^{-2} + \dots ) v = Iv + A^{-1} v + A^{-2} v + \dots \\ &= \lambda^0 v + \lambda^{-1} v + \lambda^{-2} v + \dots  = \Bigl( \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (\lambda^{-1})^k \Bigr) v = \frac{1}{1 - \lambda^{-1}} v. \end{align*}  $$
Hence the eigenvalues of $B$ are $1/(1-\lambda^{-1})$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

The same game with geometric series also informs the observations about $B = (I - A^{-1})^{-1}$; we have
$$ B = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty (A^{-1})^k = (I - A^{-1})^{-1}. $$

Comment: Whenever I cannot proceed with a calculation, there's always something to do with the geometric series... I need to study that, probably my foundation is faulty. Thank you.

Comment: Geometric series are genuinely very powerful and important, and show up all over the place. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: show that $B=(I-A^{-1})^{-1}$, thus by spectral mapping theorem, the eigenvalues of $B$ are $(1-\lambda^{-1})^{-1}$ where $\lambda = 2, 3$ are eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: What has this to do with the spectral theorem?

Comment: spectral *mapping* theorem

Comment: I haven't learned the spectral theorem but thanks for the answer!